# Book of short stories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There was a book of short stories that I read as a kid.  I loved it and checked it out all the time in my schools library.  The one story that sticks out is about a group of children in a perfect world but they were mutants, not perfect. They were kept in a nursery for these kinds.  The story is told from the point of view of a kid named MLN or as he calls himself Emellan.  Does anyone else remember this story?

Comment: You read it as a kid? Was that 10 years ago? 20 years ago? 50?

Comment: This has been asked and answered twice before, in [Short story about mutant children who all have names starting with “Em”?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53726/short-story-about-mutant-children-who-all-have-names-starting-with-em) and [Looking for late 70s short story anthology, we'd call it YA now. May have included Leiber's “A Pail of Air”](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31924/looking-for-late-70s-short-story-anthology-wed-call-it-ya-now-may-have-includ).

Comment: The story you remember is [The Others](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?190750) by J. Hunter Holly.

Comment: @JohnRennie best way is to add that as an answer, then, _if_ the OP indicates this is the answer they were looking for, mark it as duplicate. Although in this case, the OP is looking for the entire book, not just the single story.

Comment: IMO there's enough concrete evidence that this is a duplicate (the name alone pretty much nails it) without the OP needing to come back.

Comment: @JohnRennie OP wanted the book not just the story. Why not make an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The short story is [The Others by Roger Elwood](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?190750), and it has only been anthologised once so the book must be [The Other Side of Tomorrow](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?264782).

The story has been asked about before in:

- [Short story about mutant children who all have names starting with "Em"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53726/short-story-about-mutant-children-who-all-have-names-starting-with-em)
- [Looking for late 70s short story anthology, we'd call it YA now. May have included Leiber's "A Pail of Air"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31924/looking-for-late-70s-short-story-anthology-wed-call-it-ya-now-may-have-includ)

And the compilation The Other Side of the Sky has also been discussed in:

- [Trying to find the name of a sci fi anthology book, or just the titles of one or more stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143593/trying-to-find-the-name-of-a-sci-fi-anthology-book-or-just-the-titles-of-one-or)